# How to handle multiple WSDL files with PHP?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have 3 WSDL files for "Add Projects", "Add Employees for Projects", "Project Update".

If I write 3 function in same class. How to assign 3 WSDL file using "SoapServer".

for example:

```
Class Project{
   public function addProject(){}
   public function addEmployeesForProject(){}
   public function updateProject(){}
}  

$server = new SoapServer(/* how to assign 3 WSDL files*/);
$server->setClass('Project');
$server->handle();
```

I can assign one WSDL file like this..

```
$server = new SoapServer("addProject.wsdl");
```

**But someone please explain how to handle more WSDL files in same class.**

Answer (score 0):

You can merge wsdl files to one, take a look:

[WSDLMerge](https://github.com/lenardg/WSDLMerge)